# WebGL (OpenGL ES) is only drawing first set of tiles in x direction

Tags: javascript, html, opengl-es, webgl

So, I have a for loop that draws my tiles, selecting only the ones at a range I specify. This works fine.Then, I change my x and y coordinate with input and draw.

It works for my z range (scrolling until out of tile space) but for my -x and +x it will only draw the original boundaries. Ex: -3,+3
What would be wrong here?

EDIT:

```
for(var _x = (camA.x-3); _x <= (camA.x+3); _x++) {      
  for(var _z = (camA.z-8); _z < (camA.z); _z++) {
    GL.bindBuffer(GL.ARRAY_BUFFER, grid[_x][_z].vbo.v);
    GL.vertexAttribPointer(p.vertex_position, 3, GL.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    GL.enableVertexAttribArray(p.vertex_position);

    GL.bindBuffer(GL.ARRAY_BUFFER, grid[_x][_z].vbo.t);
    GL.vertexAttribPointer(p.texture_coord, 2, GL.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
    GL.enableVertexAttribArray(p.texture_coord);

    if(tex == null || tex != grid[_x][_z].assetI) {
      tex = grid[_x][_z].assetI;

      GL.activeTexture(GL.TEXTURE0);
      GL.bindTexture(GL.TEXTURE_2D, v2.textures[tex]);
      GL.uniform1i(p.sampler, 0);
    }

    GL.uniformMatrix4fv(p.proj_mat, false, v2.proj_mat);
    GL.uniformMatrix4fv(p.mv_mat, false, v2.mv_mat);
    GL.drawArrays(GL.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);
  }
  _z = (camA.z-8);
}
```

thanks

Comment: Possibly if share some code block with us. we might be more usefull i think..

Comment: are your tiles in world space? `v2.mv_mat` or whatever you're setting `p.mv_mat` to doesn't seem to be changing for each tile which is what I'd expect.

Comment: it doesnt change there, but in the code preceding this for loop it does.